# Create multiple text layers in QGIS from one text file

Tags: qgis, layers, csv

I am using QGIS 2.10 and I want to import data which I have on a text file. This text file is a csv comma separated with four columns (first raw is the name of columns):

id,coordinate_y,coordinate_x,data
1,38.756812,-8.961929,Data 1
1,38.756812,-8.961929,Data 2
1,38.756812,-8.961929,Data 3
2,38.756812,-8.961929,Data 4
2,37.18333,-7.96667,Data 5
3,39.02292,-9.10491,Data 6
4,41.19508,-7.98096,Data 7

(The file contains in fact much more data, this is just an example)

If I import this to QGIS I get just on layer, because I add just one file obviously. But I want to have different layers, exactly as many layers as differente id values I have (first colum). So in the example above I would want to have four layers.

Of course, I could transform my csv file into different files containing just the same id values before importing to QGIS. But I wonder if QGIS has an option to create new layers based on an specific feature. That is, can I import just one file to QGIS and after that split into different layers?

Comment: Do you have *Split vector layer* tool in  `Vector | Data Management Tools` ? If not, you may find it in the `Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector general tools | Split vector layer`.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad to hear that. I was honestly unsure about how version 2.10 menus were configured.